# Python Multiprocessing to speed up I/O and Groupby/Sum

Tags: python, pandas, python-multiprocessing

I have a dataset with ~200 million rows, ~10 grouping variables, and ~20 variables to sum, and is a ~50GB csv. The first thing I did was see what the runtime was run sequentially but in chunks. It's a bit more complicated because some of the groupbys are actually in another dataset at a different aggregation level so it's only ~200mb. So the relevant code right now looks like this:

```
group_cols = ['cols','to','group','by']
cols_to_summarize = ['cols','to','summarize']
groupbys = []
df = pd.read_csv("file/path/df.csv",chunksize=1000000)
for chunk in df:
  chunk = chunk.merge(other_df,left_on="id",right_index=True,how="inner")
  groupbys.append(chunk.groupby(group_cols)[cols_to_summarize].sum())
finalAgg = pd.concat(groupbys).groupby(group_cols)[cols_to_summarize].sum()
```

Each chunk takes roughly 5 seconds to process so the 200 chunks takes about 15-20 minutes. The server I'm working on has 16 cores, so I'm hoping to get a bit of speedup here, if I could get it to 2-3 minutes that would be amazing.

But when I try to use multiprocess I'm struggling to get much speedup at all. Based on my googling I thought that would help with reading in CSVs but I'm wondering if multiple processes can't read the same CSV and maybe I should split it up first? Here's what I tried and it took longer than the sequential run:

```
def agg_chunk(start):
  [pull in small dataset]
  chunk = pd.read_csv("file/path/df.csv",skiprows=range(1,start+1),nrows=1000000)
  chunk = chunk.merge(other_df,left_on="id",right_index=True,how="inner")
  return chunk.groupby(group_cols)[cols_to_summarize].sum()
if __name__ == "__main__":
  pool = mp.Pool(16)
  r = list(np.array(range(200))*1000000)
  groupbys = pool.map(agg_chunk,r)
  finalAgg = pd.concat(groupbys).groupby(group_cols)[cols_to_summarize].sum()
```

Is there a better way to do this? The extra [pull in small dataset] piece takes about 5 seconds, but doubling the time per process and then dividing by 16 should still be a pretty good speedup right? Instead the parallel version has been running for half an hour and is still not complete. Also is there some way to pass the dataset to each process instead of making each re-create it again?

Comment: if your task is I/O bound you should use either threads or async execution

Comment: I thought according to my readings that threads don't help I/o bound tasks while new processes did. Does async execution improve I/o? I thought the difference was just how the processes were collected, where synchronized meant it waits for all processes to complete before continuing while async would run the next command immediately. Is that not the case?

Comment: Have you tried chunking the csv file yourself instead of letting pandas do it for you? By using skiprows you're reading the file multiple times. It would be better if you either read the file into memory (might be a problem considering its size) or split the file.

Comment: What do you mean reading it multiple times? It doesn't fit into memory I figured reading reading x% of the file using skiprows should take x% of the time, is that not the case?